# where can I find the default returned features by dfs [featuretools]

Tags: featuretools

quick question:

Is there some doc / resource where to find the default features output by featuretools dfs?

For example if i use `trans_primitives=["time_since_previous"]` it seems that it outputs time in between transactions and also time from first transaction.

It would be great if I could find somewhere the default output from the transformers, and also, the different options for each argument.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features returned by DFS will vary based on the entity set and the primitives used. The default primitives used by DFS are listed below as defined in the [API Reference](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/generated/featuretools.dfs.html#featuretools.dfs):

```py
agg_primitives: [
    "sum",
    "std",
    "max",
    "skew",
    "min",
    "mean",
    "count",
    "percent_true",
    "num_unique",
    "mode",
]
```

```py
trans_primitives: [
    "day",
    "year",
    "month",
    "weekday",
    "haversine",
    "num_words",
    "num_characters",
]
```

Yes, the [`time_since_previous`](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/generated/featuretools.primitives.TimeSincePrevious.html#featuretools-primitives-timesinceprevious) does output the time between transactions with different options available for the `unit` parameter:

> unit (str) – Defines the unit of time to count from. Defaults to Seconds. Acceptable values: years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds

Let me know if this helps.